# What's the power problem?

Tags: engine, power, yamaha, two-stroke, boat

2-stroke marine engine (200 Yam) starts and revs just fine out of gear. Put into gear and will only achieve 40kph or so.

Old petrol (50:1)? Changed tanks and new fuel - same.

Boat hull dirty? A little, but exactly the same 6 months earlier, pulled 80+kph.

Heads off, no tracking on gaskets, but some emulsification in a couple of bores. Rings?

Comment: Prop shaft bearings seizing? Glands seizing?

Answer (score 0):

Many people have experienced [clogs in their fuel system](https://www.allcoast.com/threads/yamaha-150-power-loss-solved.41979/), often the high pressure fuel filter.  A simple remedy may be adding Yamalube Ring-Free Fuel Additive, 2 oz. per gallon, as a shock treatment to your fuel system and power head.  A competitor called StarTron Ring Clean works similarly but even better, according to many Yamaha owners.